# How to trigger window.onerror in angular?

Tags: javascript, console, onerror

I know there are many other posts about this topic, but I still can't get it working.
I am using **Angular 8** in my project and I want to send the browser console message to a server log file.
Could someone please clearifiy does questions for me:

1. When does the window.onerror get trigged?  - right know I put the function within the constructor, is that ok so?
   Does it get trigged, if I serve the project local?

> ```
>   window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
>       alert(errorMsg + ' ' + lineNumber);
>     };
> ```

2. What do I have to do to get it triggered? (or does for example a thrown error of a missing certificate - trigger this function?)

> console.error('test') - does this trigger it?

> throw new Error() - or this?

3. Does Console-Errors like CORS will trigger this function?
4. I also read that it would get triggered if an img or script source is not avilable.

> app.compentent.html: `<img src="test.png">`

> app.copmentent.ts in the constructor (the code of point one)

But I still don't get the alert to display.

I am grateful for any help - thanks

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Comment: Thanks - but I already visited this site, but there I have still a view questions. Could you please give me an explation of where to use this function? (and why should I use it - what's the benefit of it?) @Jaromanda X

Comment: @angularQuestions look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event for an explanation

Comment: Will the Angular's `ErrorHandler` also catch errors passed to `window.onerror` handler?
I am suggesting that you will have the error within `ErrorHandler.handleError(error)` - so you can log that error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may work for you. I used it in some Vue.js code to test triggering window.onerror(). Using eval() should allow you to bypass the compile-time checks of Angular and putting it in window.onload() will ensure it is evaluated after page load.

```js
window.onerror = function (message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  alert('onerror called: ' + message);
}

window.onload = function () {
  eval('undefined_function()');
}
```

As a security note, don't use eval() in production, especially if user input could get anywhere near it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried triggering error function with your code

```js
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
      alert(errorMsg + ' ' + lineNumber);
    };


callingnonexistancefunction()
```

It is triggering while calling a non exist function.

Hope you'll get some reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I still can't get it working.
Because in Angular it will not compile if the function is not defined. @Diwakar
So is there another way to test window.onerror function?